# Formatting a lot of JSON mashed into a legit format

Tags: java, json, validation, gson, import.io

So I'm having this problem about the output of an import.io command. My results' format is the following:

```
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself}
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself}
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself}
...
```

When I would like to have something along the lines of:

```
[
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself},
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself},
...
{a line which is a valid JSON by itself}
]
```

In order to get them I had to download them into a single document like this:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream results = p.getInputStream();
FileWriter writer_results = new FileWriter ("resultadosRAW.json");
try(
//Scanner object for reading the file
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(results);
)
{
//Reading each line of file using Scanner class
while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
    writer_results.write(scnr.nextLine());
}
}
writer_results.close();
```

And I have no idea how could I extract the legit JSONs from the document I created. When I was doing some tests, using small sized documents, I was able to do something along the lines of creating a JSON array, then adding each string to the whole array, so I ended with a valid JSON array but the size of this document is too great for this (I actually spent 3,7 hours in getting the 100mbps file)

If it was some other way I could run the whole command again, but I would prefer to work on that huge string instead of having to wait again. Is there any way of getting a valid json from this mess?

Right now I'm using Eclipse in Java, and also the GSON libraries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you need to do with this file exactly? Create another huge file representing a valid JSON array? Process every JSON object it contains?

Comment: If you placed `[]` on the outside of the data without commas between the lines, you don't have valid JSON

Comment: @JBNizet What I want is to process every json, and I already have the code for that, but in order to use it I need to have a valid document to read, because now my parser just throws the MalformedJsonException.

Comment: If every line is a valid JSON by itself, then it's easy: just read the file line by line, and parse each line, instead of trying to parse the whole file at once (which wouldn't work anymore if the file is too large).

Comment: @JBNizet Problem is, in fact the file is more like:
{valid JSON}{validJSON{validJSON} and so on. I'm not sure how could I go line by line, as it's just a huge string...